# Extrema of $\exp(x+y+z)$ on $2$D-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, compactness, lagrange-multiplier

Find, if existent, the global extrema of $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},\, (x,y,z)\mapsto \exp(x+y+z)$ on $M:= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3 : \exp(x)+y^2+z^2=1  \right\}$.

---

Since $M$ is compact, we should be able to find both, global maximum and global minimum on $M$. However, my computation yields only one critical point.

**My computation:**

Set $\Phi(x,y,z,\lambda):=\varphi(x,y,z)-\lambda\cdot (\exp(x)+y^2+z^2-1)$. Letting $D\Phi=0$ gives the following equations:

$\exp(x,y,z)=\lambda\exp(x)=2\lambda y=2\lambda z$ and $\exp(x)+y^2+z^2=1$ which results in $x=\ln(2y),\, y=z$ and ultimately gives us $y_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$, of which we can only use the positive solution since $x=\ln(2y)$. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: The issue is that $M$ is not compact. You can have $x$'s be far flung negative numbers while being arbitrarily close to the cylinder $y^2+z^2=1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for the comment, that's true, $M$ is not even bounded and I guess that now we have to look at the values of $\varphi$ as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$, right? Or is there more to it?